# Oracle BEA Workshop sql statements logged

Tags: sql, oracle, weblogic-10.x

We are using Oracle's BEA Workshop 10 tool.  When we run our application, all of our sql statements are being logged.  I need to turn this off.   Any suggestions?  I have looked at  our config files and don't see anything that says SQL=TRACE.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm this seems googleable to me..

Comment: Try [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FE13226_01%2Fworkshop%2Fdocs81%2Fdoc%2Fen%2Fportal%2Fjava-class%2Fcom%2Fbea%2Fp13n%2Futil%2Fdebug%2FDebug.html&ei=sO5QUOKvE4b2rAHxuIC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNF5KNRFnVMiq_aDox9H-pcDiK9u6A)